# Difficulty saving form information to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to implement a commenting system for a blog application I've been working on. However, I've been having a lot of difficulty getting my form to save inputted information to my database. 
The code for my comment's controller is:

```
def create
    @comment = @wad.comments.create(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
        flash[:sucess] = "Thanks for posting!"
        redirect_to wad_comments_path(@wad)
    else
        flash[:error] = "Failed submission. Please try again."          
        render 'index'
    end
end

.
.
.

private

def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
end
```

The code for my model:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
attr_accessor :content
belongs_to :wad
belongs_to :user
end
```

and the code for my form:

```
<%= form_for([@wad, @wad.comments.create]) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Where "wad" is a regular post. I've checked my server log, and in the params is a :comment hash containing :content. I'm not sure why, then, it's not saving to the database. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any errors in your server log? Some `NoMethodError`, perhaps?

Comment: remove `attr_accessor` from Comment model and post error log if any

Answer (score 1):

why you are using `attr_accessor :content` instead use column and modify following line

```
<%= form_for([@wad, @wad.comments.create]) do |f| %>
```

as

```
<%= form_for([@wad, @wad.comments.build]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Indeed, attr_accessor is not needed there.